# SQL Key Value Pair Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, key-value

I have two tables:

Product Table

- ID (PK), Description, CategoryID, SegmentID, TypeID, SubTypeID, etc.

Attribute Table

- ID (PK), ProductID (FK), Key, Value

And I would like to query these two tables in a join that returns 1 row for each product with all of the Key/Value pair records in the Attribute table returned in a single column, perhaps separated by a pipe character `(Key1: Value1 | Key2: Value2 | Key3: Value3 | etc.)`.  Each product could have a different number of key/value pairs, with some products have as few as 2-3 and some having as many as 30.  I would like to figure out how to get the query results to look something like this (perhaps selected into a new table):

product.ID, product.Description, [special attributes column], product.CategoryID, product.SegmentID, etc.

example result:

```
65839, "WonderWidget", "HeightInInches: 26 | WeightInLbs: 5 | Color: Black", "Widgets", "Commerical"
```

Conversely, it would be helpful to figure out how to take the query results, formatted as mentioned above, and push them back into the original Attribute table.  For example, if we output the query above into a table where the [special attributes column] was modified (values updated/corrected by a human), it would be nice to know how to use the table containing the [special attributes column] to update the original Attribute table. I think for that to be possible, the Attribute.ID field would need to be included in the query output.

In the end, what I am trying to accomplish is way to export the Product and Attribute data out to 1 row per product with all the attribute data so that it can be reviewed/updated/corrected by a human in something as simple as an Excel file, and then pushed back into SQL.  I think I can figure out how to do all of that once I get over the hurdle of figuring out how to get the products and attributes out as one row per product. Perhaps the correct answer is to pivot all of the attributes into columns, but I'm afraid the query would be incredibly wide and wasteful. Open to suggestions for this as well.  Changing to a document type database is not an option right now; need to figure out the best way to handle this in relational SQL.

Comment: it depends on the database technology you are using (Oracle, SQL Server, Postgres, MySQL etc) . The version would be relevant as well.

Comment: I wouldn't invent yet another "key/value" syntax. Use the JSON capabilities of your DBMS and aggregate the rows into proper JSON values so that accessing the keys (and values) will be a lot easier later. https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=ef5f4a66f874a2ec0d4c180a4e31d2ed

Comment: Using MS SQL 11.0.2100 on a legacy box for testing...the production solution will go into SQL Standard or Express hosted in Azure.

Comment: Sounds like what I need is grouped concatenation, a feature that appears to have been added via the STRING_AGG function in later versions of SQL.  I attempted to add a scalar-value UDF based on this article, but to no avail.  https://sqlperformance.com/2014/08/t-sql-queries/sql-server-grouped-concatenation I get a "ConcatFunction is not a recognized built-in function name" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first need to group the Key value pairs. This can be achieved using a concat operatoor like ||, you need to think about nulls as well. NUll concatenated with NULL is still NULL in most DBs.

```
SELECT ProductID, Key || ':' || Value as KeyValue FROM AttributeTable
```

Then you would need to group those using an aggregating function like STRING_AGG (Assuming SQL Server above 2017). Other databases have different aggregate functions Mysql f ex uses GROUP_CONCAT

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/mysql-group_concat-function/

```
SELECT ProductID, STRING_AGG( Key || ':' || Value, '|') as Key Value FROM AttributeTable GROUP BY ProductId
```

I can expand on the answer if you can provide more information.

Comment: Loading some test data now and will report back.  This is MS SQL.

Comment: I think what I am trying to accomplish is possible via grouped concatenation, but I don't have a version of SQL handy with that feature;  all good.  This pointed me in the right direction.